# Compile Only With Dependencies

Tags: css, less

Okay, Let's say I have a bunch of less files that compile to one big monolithic css file.

It has a lot of 'component'-like things, i.e. `alert.less`, `sidebar.less`, `third-form.less`, etc. (those are just examples)

Now all variables are put in `variables.less`, and `alert.less` might `extend` a `class` from, say, `item.less`

Now this is the question. Let's say I want to get *JUST* `alert.less` is there a way to make less compile it with only it's dependencies? (i.e. it gets *only* the variables it needs from `variables.less`)

This might be hard, or downright impossible, but it shouldn't hurt to ask. So, is it possible, and how should I do it?

Comment: I can't see the problem. To "get just `alert.less`" you do compile *just* `alert.less` and it will compile fine (provided you need to put `@import "variables.less";` there). That's it. (and `extend` for non-existing class of `item.less` will skip silently).

Comment: @seven-phases-max I've tried it, but it importing say, `variables.less`, will import everything, and importing my mixins would also import the whole thing, which breaks the 'just the css with dependecy' that I am aiming for.

Comment: Ok, now I see what you mean. So... **#1:** If you plan your mixins to be re-usable without bloating the depended components - make them parametric (see [A](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-not-outputting-the-mixin) and [B](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1399#issuecomment-33680478)). **#2** Importing everything from `variables.less` shoudld not be a problem since it contains only variables. **#3** Since #1 and #2 are not always possible there's [`@import (reference) ...;`](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-reference) feature.

Comment: @seven-phases-max why not putting these kind of comments in the answers right away?

Comment: @Lipis I would but I think the answer needs to be a bit more descriptive and detailed (and this is slightly beyond my writing skills, so I hope someone will write such answer eventually).